# C# code to query Access DB linked table with authentication

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have MS Access (.accdb) file with a linked table pointing to DB2 Database. To access linked table or to query it, I have to enter the credentials.
In C# code, I am passing required parameters (Provider,Data Source, UID, Password). But everytime I run the code, it opens a pop-up to enter the creds. How do I overcome this?

```
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\abcServer\defFolder\AccFile.accdb;UID=ab12;Pwd=***;Persist Security Info=False";
string strSQL = "SELECT count(*) FROM tableAbc";
using(OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString)) 
{    
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);  
    try {  
        connection.Open();  
        using(OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {  
            while (reader.Read()) {  
                int num1 = reader.GetInt32(0);
                break;
            }  
        }  
    } catch (Exception ex) {  
        msg = ex.Message;  
    }  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does your `.accdb` use ODBC, OLE-DB, or some other way to connect to DB2?

Comment: @Dai - The file uses ODBC Database connection to connect to DB2.

Comment: You should be able to specify saved credentials for DB2 inside the ODBC connection properties inside Access, or Control Panel > Administrative Tools > ODBC Data Sources, by creating a Data Source Name that you reference inside the `.accdb`.

Comment: I update the connection string in Linked manager with .accdb file. But still it opens a pop-up for credentials. This time, it is setting the password automatically but User Id is null. I wanted to override the pop-up option and pass creds within connection string.

Comment: You’ll need to consult the documentation for your DB2 library.

Comment: In your ODBC Data Source Administrator, are you sure you've chosen to save your password?  If the password is not saved, it will always prompt you to enter it.  If it's saved, it shouldn't ask for it again.

Comment: This is what I needed to do. I opened the ODBC Data Source (32 bit) as Admin -> Switch to System DSN tab -> Double click on Database name -> Enter credentials. Reopening the file resolved the pop-up issue.

Answer (score 0):

separately, you can shorten your code by removing the reader part and replacing with ExecuteScalar which will return the value in the first row and first column of the data set. Basically, when you expect just one value returned (in your case a count) then you can use ExecuteScalar.

Replace:

```
    using(OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {  
        while (reader.Read()) {  
            int num1 = reader.GetInt32(0);
            break;
        }  
    }
```

With:

```
int num1 = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```